# Forbidden business practices in games

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis, games-toys

Charging interest or surplussage on real loans to a fellow Jew is forbidden but may one do so with in-game play money or with in-game commodities?

Comment: Just a thought for further research that may lead to an answer: I wonder whether the answer is different depending on whether the loan is real-world or [in-universe](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-universe). For example: If you borrow fictional money in a game, does the debt continue to another game between the same players? does it continue to someone who takes over the debtor's spot at the game table? If the respective answers to those are Yes and No, that sounds like a real-world loan; if they're No and Yes, it sounds like an in-universe loan.

Comment: Why do you think it may be forbidden?

Comment: Because since the in-game commodities influence real world enjoyment, that might be sufficient to make this a problem.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Pently of things influence real world enjoyment without being money. How could anyone possible construe fictional game money as "currency" and not "commodity"?

Comment: Ribbis is forbidden with commodities as well as currency

Comment: So, what? You need a heter iska to play Monopoly?

Comment: It would seem so

Comment: SEE THIS LINK: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81688/ribbis-and-onaah-in-monopoly/91652#91652